# How to stream a fixed list using Spring webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, reactive

I want to use `Flux` to stream a defined amount of data to the client. So that the client receives the data one by one and does not have to wait until my server prepared the full list.

Therefore I created the following example. I'd expect the numbers being printed each with a delay of 1 seconds:

```
@RestController
public class WebfluxServlet {
    private static final List<String> inventory = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");

    @GetMapping("/flux1")
    public Flux<String> flux1() {
        return Flux.fromIterable(inventory).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    }

    @GetMapping("/flux2")
    public Flux<String> flux2() {
        Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        Flux<String> events = Flux.fromIterable(inventory);
        return Flux.zip(events, interval, (key, value) -> key);
    }
}
```

Using simple `curl localhost:8080/flux` to test the endpoint:

- `/flux1` immediatly outputs `12345` without any delay.
- `/flux2` waits 5 seconds, then outputs `12345` at once.

Both is not as I expected.

Interestingly, if I add `@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)`, I'm getting the stream events directly. But my goal is to have `stream+json`. How can I get this?

Comment: Your example works great in my case. It's my only dependency: `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'`

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I had a `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` still configured (as I had a blocking normal api before). The filter cached the response somehow, so the response was only emitted entirely.

Without the filter my example works as @Vusal told.